# Model/Mesh Fractures

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, artifacts

Im new to blender, and new to the site. Ive researched my questions on the internet, and asked a few people, and they all basically sent me here. So i was hoping that I could get some assistance.

So Im new to blender, and starting to model some of my own assets for a Game my colleagues and I are building. Here is my current dilemma.

As I venture further into my model, and I lop cut and drag, and I extract shapes and build I come out with amazing results. However, when I add a subsurface modifier, and start to do more intricate details, and adding little things here and there, I am finding that my mesh is starting to fracture. When I turn the subsurface modifier off, if all recorrects itself.

Im getting, for lack of a better term, "phantom" faces and 
edges and these "semi filled" faces appear and I cant figure out how to get rid of them. Im spending HOURS trying to figure out how to repair all my beautiful work, and I really think that solving the actual problem is something I should think about doing. So please, any assistance, would be most appreciated.

I can add a couple of images to further my explanations, if needed and someone can tell me how.

Thanks Community

Chris

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJvW.jpg

[image]

Comment: Images would be helpful. You can also upload your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ copy the resulting link and paste it into your original question using the "edit" button. Without knowing anything more I will add that the order of Modifiers is important.

Comment: Ok. How do I upload the images I have here? Im going to upload my file right now.

Comment: I uploaded the file Dontwalk. I hope that helps.

Comment: Also Like I said before, Im new to blender, and Im learning to build meshes for a game engine. So any extra critics and criticisms are welcome.

Comment: When you click on the "edit" button of your original post in the panel above the text box there is a little square with a simple graphic of a mountain and sun. Click on that (You may need a certain amount of reputation to use it). Alternately you can create an account here http://imgur.com/ upload an image(s) copy the link and paste that into your original question.

Comment: Excellent. A gentleman, and a scholar.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2GC7C 

And here are the images I took. I uploaded them as requested to imgur.

Comment: Try going into Edit Mode selecting all vertices by pressing "A" (You may need to press it a couple of times). Then in the tool bar on the left (Press "T" if it's not visible) "Remove Doubles".

Comment: Ok that helped quite a bit but I still got some random edges and crazy faces appearing in places.

Comment: Ok, you have some faces inside the model that shouldn't be there. On a side note - in Object Mode set the Shading in the Tool Bar to "Smooth". And in your Sub Surf Modifier you have the Preview set to "4" and the Render is set to "2". So the render wont be as smooth as what you are seeing as a preview. Generally "2" is enough. The larger you make that number the slower your renders will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Faces inside your model that shouldn't be there. 
[image: Unwanted Face]

The best way to remove them is in Edit Mode select the bottom edge press "X" and select  "Only Edges and Faces" from the drop down menu.
[image: Selected Edge]

Also, selecting Smooth Shading in Object Mode will clean this up.
[image]